# Elastalert in Openshift Origin Container

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift-origin, elastalert

I would like to implement alerts for EFK stack, which is deployemnt in Openshift origin. To implement alerts, i used Elastalert. I used the krizsan/elastalert-docker docker image for it.

```
oc run elastalertcore --image=172.30.1.1:5000/logging/elastalert-core --port=3344 --expose
```

This will succesfully run the elastalert instance, but in the log im getting

```
Container timezone set to: Europe/Stockholm
ntpd: can't set priority: Permission denied
reset adjtime failed: Operation not permitted
creating new /var/db/ntpd.drift
adjtimex failed: Operation not permitted
dispatch_imsg in main: pipe closed
Lost child: child exited
Terminating
Waiting for Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch...
```

I gave environment varialbe

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST =logging-es
```

Elastalert cannot connect to the elastic search in open shift origin. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Docker image from Docker hub doesn't work as-is on Openshift often due to Security Context Constraints.

To avoid permission errors, you can add :

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

enabling a pod with default service account to run with anyuid SCC. Be aware that it can impact all pod running within the project if you don't specify explicitly an other service account in your pod definition.

Comment: Noting that this can only be done if you are a cluster admin. It cannot be done if you are only a project admin. This means you cannot do this on OpenShift Online as you aren't a cluster admin. If you encounter images which require they be run as root, you should encourage the authors of the image to not require the use of root and instead set up images to run as any user ID as any container deployment system, not just OpenShift, that values security isn't going to allow stuff to run as root.

Comment: You right, @expuser111 explicitly mention Openshift Origin. Maybe the better way is to build your own image avoiding the use of root.